# how can I solve this react error after building

Tags: reactjs, build

everyone!
I got Minified React error after building react project.
[This is Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imurP.png)

I am using React@18.2.0
please help me, how can I solve this issues?
Thanks so much.

I tried to down React version to 18.0.0
Also updated useEffect. but I can't solve this issue
[This is my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5kxz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.